# Android: CardsLib Card not displaying title

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-5.0-lollipop, spannablestring, cardslib

I'm using Mariotti's CardsLib to create a list with Cards. I create cards (in a for loop) as shown below:

```
CustomCard aCard = new CustomCard(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
CardHeader aHeader = new CardHeader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
aHeader.setTitle(item.getHeaderText());

aCard.addCardHeader(aHeader);
aCard.setSpannableMainTitle(true);
aCard.setmSsbTitle(CustomSpannableBuilderForHome.getSpannedText(item));

CardThumbnail thumbnail = new CardThumbnail(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
thumbnail.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
aCard.addCardThumbnail(thumbnail);
cards.add(0, aCard);
```

CustomCard is a class extending Card class. I created this class because I need to assign an SpannableStringBuilder instance, instead of simple String. This is CustomCard:

```
public class CustomCard extends Card {

    protected boolean isSpannableMainTitle;

    /**
     * Main Title
     */
    protected SpannableStringBuilder mSsbTitle;

    public SpannableStringBuilder getmSsbTitle() {
        return mSsbTitle;
    }

    public void setmSsbTitle(SpannableStringBuilder mSsbTitle) {
        this.mSsbTitle = mSsbTitle;
    }

    public boolean isSpannableMainTitle() {
        return isSpannableMainTitle;
    }

    public void setSpannableMainTitle(boolean isSpannableMainTitle) {
        this.isSpannableMainTitle = isSpannableMainTitle;
    }

    public CustomCard(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {
        //Add simple title to header
        if (view != null) {
            TextView mTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_title);
            if (mTitleView != null)
            {
                mTitleView.setText(isSpannableMainTitle? mSsbTitle : mTitle);
                if (isSpannableMainTitle) mTitleView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine prior to using maps api V2. Today, the card's title does not appear when the text does not contain spans. If it does have spans, only spans are shown. It is also worth mentioning that the title to be set, is ALWAYS an instance of SpannableStringBuilder.
For example:

Text1 = This is a text with no spans

Text2 = This is a (text) with (spans) <--- where () denote the presence of span.

This is the output:

Card 1:

Picture + Header + no text

Card 2:

Picture + Header + (text) (spans)

That is, the first card has no text, while the latter displays only spanned text (i.e. This is a with, all of them ignored).

As I said, this behavior started once I included Maps API V2. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the problem. The first card doesn't display the title, but the is the title  != null ?

Comment: For the activity using cards, the title to be set is always an instance of SpannableStringBuilder, therefore, isSpannableMainTitle is true. I've debugged my code and mSsbTitle is not null. However, mSsbTitle might not contain spans inside, which causes the card to display no title. When it does have some spans, the card displays only those but not the rest of the text. I used parenthesis in text2 to mark which words were spanned, and the result in Card 2 is Picture + Header + spanned text only (rest of the text does not appear, that is, this is a with, all missing.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, this code was working perfectly prior to google maps api v2 addition to my project.

Comment: I still cannot get this to work like it did before. Any suggestions??

Comment: This is an issue in nexus 4 devices